# how to change the number of positional argument?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def sigmaV_B():

    if data['BidPrice'].shift(1)-data['BidPrice'] > 0:
        return 0
    elif data['BidPrice'].shift(1)-data['BidPrice'] == 0:
        return data['BidVolume']-data['BidVolume'].shift(1)
    else:
        return data['BidVolume']
def sigmaV_A():

    if data['AskPrice']-data['AskPrice'].shift(1) > 0:
        return 0
    elif data['AskPrice']-data['AskPrice'].shift(1) == 0:
        return data['AskVolume']-data['AskVolume'].shift(1)
    else:
        return data['AskVolume']

def OI():
        return sigmaV_B-sigmaV_A

data.apply(OI)
```

I want to apply OI to my dataframe but it does not work and report an error
'TypeError: OI() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'
Can someone tell me how can I solve it? I am a beginner to python so I make very basic mistakes, thank you so much for helping me

Comment: You might've meant `result = OI()`? Although none of those if conditions will work. You seem to have a few core misunderstandings of how Pandas Objects behave. What are you trying to do?

Comment: try this to `OI`, `def OI(v)`, and since you mentioned you are a beginner in python, you should try understanding it a bit more before you move on to pandas and dataframes, the reason why I'm stating this is because your error clearly says what went wrong

Comment: The reason why you are getting a type error is because the `apply` methods calls the function you provided with the current cell value, since the function that you gave does not accept any argument it errors.

Comment: @HenryEcker can you recommend some articles or videos for beginners to pandas? I believe what I learnt is far from enought to handle my assignment as you said i show a few core misunderstanding of how Pandas Objects behave. Thank you for being helpful

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `apply()` function provided by `pandas` is able to apply a given function on `rows/columns/cells` but you are trying to apply a function on the entire `DataFrame`. I highly recommend going through the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and thinking about what has to be done, for a while.( ;) )

BTW if your functions work properly changing them in the following way would do the trick.

```
def sigmaV_B(data):

    if data['BidPrice'].shift(1)-data['BidPrice'] > 0:
        return 0
    elif data['BidPrice'].shift(1)-data['BidPrice'] == 0:
        return data['BidVolume']-data['BidVolume'].shift(1)
    else:
        return data['BidVolume']
def sigmaV_A(data):

    if data['AskPrice']-data['AskPrice'].shift(1) > 0:
        return 0
    elif data['AskPrice']-data['AskPrice'].shift(1) == 0:
        return data['AskVolume']-data['AskVolume'].shift(1)
    else:
        return data['AskVolume']

def OI(data):
        return sigmaV_B(data)-sigmaV_A(data)

OI(data)
```

Comment: thank you, i will read through the documentation first

Comment: I replaced my code with yours but it does not work. 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' is shown.
Btw, I understand why mine is not working b/c apply works on column/roll instead of a whole dataframe